# If $||AB-I||=\epsilon<1$ then $||A^{-1}-B||<||B||(\frac{\epsilon}{1-\epsilon})$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, matrix-norms

I'm stucked in this problem:

> Prove that if $||AB-I||=\epsilon<1$ then
>   $||A^{-1}-B||<||B||(\frac{\epsilon}{1-\epsilon})$

---

**My process:**
1) We have that $||AB-I||=||-(AB-I)||=||I-AB||$.

2) Since $||AB-I||=||I-AB||<1$ then $(AB)^{-1}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{(I-AB)^k}$ then $||(AB)^{-1}||=||\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{(I-AB)^k}||<\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}||{(I-AB)^k}||$ *(this by the triangular inequality)* $\leq\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{||(I-AB)||^k}$ *(this by submultiplicative property and induction: $||M^k||=||M M^{k-1}||\leq||M|| ||M^{k-1}||\leq||M||^2||M^{k-2}||\leq\cdots\leq||M||^k$)*.

3) Since $||I-AB||<1$ then $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{||I-AB||^k}$ converges to $\frac{1}{1-\epsilon}$, i.e., $||(AB)^{-1}||<\frac{1}{1-\epsilon}$.

4) Since the condition number $\kappa(A)=||A||||A^{-1}||\geq1$ for all A, then $||(AB)||||(AB)^{-1}||\geq1$ then $\frac{1}{||AB||}\leq||(AB)^{-1}||\leq\frac{1}{1-\epsilon}$.

5)By the submultiplicative property $||AB||\leq||A||||B||$ then $\frac{1}{||A||||B||}\leq\frac{1}{||AB||}$, i.e., $\frac{1}{||A||}\leq||B||(\frac{1}{1-\epsilon})$

6)**Here is my problem:** i want to have that $||A^{-1}||\leq\frac{1}{||A||}$ for have $||A^{-1}||||AB-I||\leq||B||(\frac{\epsilon}{1-\epsilon})$ where $||A^{-1}-B||=||(A^{-1}A)B-A^{-1}||\leq||A^{-1}||||AB-I||$.

### and i have what i want...

In adition i don't understad why $A^{-1}$ and $B^{-1}$ exist.

Any hint is helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** To show that $A, B$ are invertible, observe
\begin{align}
(1-\varepsilon)\|x\|\leq \|x\|-\|ABx\|\leq \|ABx\|\leq \|x\|+\|(AB-I)x\|\leq (1+\varepsilon)\|x\|
\end{align}
which means $AB$ is injective and surjective (why?). Hence $AB$ is invertible which means $A$ and $B$ are invertible.

Moreover, observe
\begin{align}
\|Bx-A^{-1}x\| \leq \|B\|_\text{op}\|x-B^{-1}A^{-1}x\|\leq \|B\|_\text{op}\|I-(AB)^{-1}\|_\text{op}\|x\|.
\end{align}

Applying your argument, then you have the result. More precisely, observe that
\begin{align}
(AB)^{-1} = [I-(I-AB)]^{-1} = I+(I-AB)+(I-AB)^2+\ldots  
\end{align}
which means 
\begin{align}
(AB)^{-1}-I = (I-AB)+(I-AB)^2+\ldots.
\end{align}
Then it follows
\begin{align}
\|I-(AB)^{-1}\|_\text{op}\leq \varepsilon +\varepsilon^2+\ldots = \frac{\varepsilon}{1-\varepsilon}.
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for your help.